# rspec pending results in falied test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec3

```
it 'should be an array and not be empty' do
  pending
  expect(a.class).to be(Array)
  expect(a.empty?).to be(false)
  expect(a.first.class).to be(ExampleClass)
end
```

When I run rspec:

```
Failures:

  1) should be an array and not be empty FIXED
     Expected pending 'No reason given' to fail. No Error was raised.
     # ./spec/example_spec.rb:19
```

Any ideas why this is being listed as a failure?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As of Rspec 3.x, pending specs are actually run, and if they pass, it's considered a failure (because if it passes, then Rspec thinks it shouldn't be pending).

You can use `skip` instead of `pending` to make sure your spec doesn't actually run.

More info: https://rspec.info/blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3/#changes-to-pending-semantics-and-introduction-of-skip

Answer (score 3):

Here's your clue:

```
should be an array and not be empty FIXED
```

Things that pass will cause a pending test to fail.  Check the docs for examples [1], [2].

1. [RSpec 2](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/pending/pending-examples)
2. [RSpec 3](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/pending-and-skipped-examples/pending-examples)